# 新規ファイルを開いた時にテキストファイルの内容を挿入したい

Tags: vim

空の新規ファイルにtemplate.txtの内容を1行目に挿入したいです。
template.txtの中身はこの3行、cの最後に改行はありません。

```
a
b
c
```

試したコマンド

```
:execute '0r template.txt'
```

もうひとつ

```
:0r !cat template.txt
```

どれも最後に改行が含まれてしまい、4行になってしまいます。
template.txtと同じ内容になるように挿入する方法を教えてください。

Comment: thinca さんの方法と同じことをしていますが、コマンドラインで指定する方法です。`vim -c '1read template.txt' -c '1d' new.txt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1行目を削除すれば大丈夫です。

`read template.txt | 1 delete _`